# swift `.reduce` function arguments not found in scope

Tags: swift, reduce

Can someone explain what's wrong with this line of Swift code?

```
zip(a, b).reduce(0) { x, y in max(x, y.0 + y.1) }
```

`a` and `b` are arrays of `Int`.  See REPL session below.  It works with

```
zip(a, b).reduce(0) { max($0, $1.0 + $1.1) }
```

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.26.9 clang-1205.0.19.55).
Type :help for assistance.
  1> let a = [0, 1, 2]
a: [Int] = 3 values {
  [0] = 0
  [1] = 1
  [2] = 2
}
  2> let b = [10, 11, 12]
b: [Int] = 3 values {
  [0] = 10
  [1] = 11
  [2] = 12
}
  3> zip(a,b).reduce(0) { max($0, $1.0 + $1.1) }  
$R0: Int = 14
  4> zip(a,b).reduce(0) { x, y in max(x, y.0 + y.1) }  
error: repl.swift:4:32: error: cannot find 'x' in scope
zip(a,b).reduce(0) { x, y in max(x, y.0 + y.1) } 
                                 ^

error: repl.swift:4:34: error: cannot find 'y' in scope
zip(a,b).reduce(0) { x, y in max(x, y.0 + y.1) } 
                                    ^

error: repl.swift:4:38: error: cannot find 'y' in scope
zip(a,b).reduce(0) { x, y in max(x, y.0 + y.1) } 
                                          ^
```

Comment: It works fine when I run it in a standalone Swift file with `swiftc`, but I can reproduce this in the playground. I'm stumped.

Comment: It works though if you assign the value (e.g `let g = zip(a,b).reduce(0) { x,y in max(x, y.0 + y.1) }`). Maybe an optimization issue (?)

Comment: Apparently the same problem as in bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13949